# email function not working after publishing to iis

Tags: asp.net

I've published my app and it is now running from IIS. the problem is that the email function in my controller no longer works when running on IIS (the email function does not send email)

I have an email function on my mvc application and when I run it, it does send an email. The problem starts after I've published my app, Its running on IIS now but the email function does not send the email anymore. How do I go about fixing this?

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SendMailToUser(string lt, string reason, string name, string fr, string ed)
        {
            bool result = false;
            result = SendMail("ntulisakhile8@gmail.com", "Leave Reaquest", "Hi Sensei,<br />I would like to take a " + lt + " leave<br/><strong>From:</strong> " + fr + " <strong>To:</strong> " + ed + " <br/>Reason: " + reason + "<br/>Regards<br/>" + name + "<br/><a href=~/Response.html>Respond</a>");

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public bool SendMail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
        {
            try
            {
                string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
                string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Timeout = 100000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                client.Send(mailMessage);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you got any exception while sending email from IIS?

Comment: *Log* the exception instead of hiding it. It's impossible to guess what's going on without any information. Perhaps the credentials are wrong. Perhaps the configuration file is missing altogether. Or perhaps SMTP access isn't enabled for that account.

Comment: @kevin Shah look at the code and you'll see what is happening to exceptions...

Comment: I agree, catching exceptions without logging them is a bad idea. No wonder you can't work out what's going wrong. Change that code so it logs the exception properly (to a file or to the windows event log), then you'll hopefully see details which will mean you have a more specific problem to deal with.

Comment: 2019-05-20 09:22:31 ::1 POST /History/SendMailToUser - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/71.0.3578.98+Safari/537.36+OPR/58.0.3135.132 http://localhost/LeaveAPPDEMO/History/Create 404 0 2 1501

Comment: I got the above from the iis log

Comment: I called the SendMailToUser function in my view but on iis  log i get a 404 error...for some reason the function is not triggered. Can someone please assist

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                data: { lt: lt, reason: rs, name: name, fr: fr, ed: ed, fr: fr },
                url: "/History/SendMailToUser",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            })